# How to append items to CSV in S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CSV in S3 and I will be getting content of this CSV file from an api i need to append all this content into that S3 file

So basically I'm fetching a CSV file from an API , since the file could be large my lambda can error out while fetching it , so I need a way to fetch this file and store it in S3. The idea I have is, The api that I'm about to use has an option where I can specify the size of that particular CSV file that I need to fetch in the header, so if I specify the file size the api will return only those content . So I can take that and put it in the S3 and iterate through remaining size and get the content and append it to the first file that I put in the S3. But I have no idea how to do it, is there a way to do it? If not give my some suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: That CSV API would have to provide more than an option to specify the size. Suspect you mean that it allows you to specify a [Content-Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range) header.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Amazon S3 cannot be modified. Therefore, it is not possible to "append" to an object.

However, there are several alternatives...

Many apps just **add more objects in S3**. Then, when consuming the information, they read those multiple objects and combine the information. This is quite standard for Big Data applications. For example, **Amazon Athena** can be given a directory as a location and it will read all objects in that directory (well, actually, that Prefix).

Another method is to **upload to S3 using [multi-part uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html)**:

> Multipart upload allows you to **upload a single object as a set of parts**. Each part is a contiguous portion of the object's data. You can upload these object parts independently and in any order. If transmission of any part fails, you can retransmit that part without affecting other parts. After all parts of your object are uploaded, Amazon S3 assembles these parts and creates the object. In general, when your object size reaches 100 MB, you should consider using multipart uploads instead of uploading the object in a single operation.

Each part has a [minimum size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html) of 5MB.

You should also be careful of your AWS Lambda function -- it can run for a **maximum of 15 minutes**. Hopefully this is enough time to retrieve all desired data. If not, you could divide the download process into 'chunks' and call the Lambda function separately for each chunk.